# load a gem's gemspec

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to load a gem's gemspec from inside my ruby script. I expected to be able to do:

```
`gem spec rake`
# ERROR:  No gem matching 'rake (>= 0)' found
```

I also tried:

```
Gem::Specification.find_by_name('rake')
# Gem::LoadError: Could not find 'rake' (>= 0) among 21 total gem(s)
```

When I do `gem spec rake` from the console I get the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rake'
```

test.rb:

```
require 'rake'
p Gem::Specification.find_by_name('rake')
```

Executed:

```
bundle install
bundle exec ruby test.rb
```

Output:

```
#<Gem::Specification:0x12c1b1c rake-10.3.1>
```